# Log exception on channel and requeue

Tags: logging, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to move messages from queues defined on a RabbitServer X to multiple RabbitMQ Server Y , Z...

In the same configuration file, i defined **several channels** (one for each queues to move).

```
<!-- Channel 1  -->
<int:channel id="one" ></int:channel>
<int:channel id="error1" ></int:channel>
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="error1" logger-name="log1" >
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="XX.XX.XX.XX:5672"  cache-mode="CONNECTION" virtual-host="/"/>
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="one" id="inboundChannelAdapter1"  queue-names="myqueue" connection-factory="connectionFactory"   error-channel="error1"  auto-startup="true"  channel-transacted="true" />
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryRmqDest" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="YY.YY.YY.YY:5672" cache-mode="CONNECTION" connection-cache-size="50" virtual-host="/"/> 
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateRmqDest" connection-factory="connectionFactoryRmqDest"/>
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="one" id="outboundChannelAdapter1" routing-key="keyMyQueue" exchange-name="direct.exchange" amqp-template="rabbitTemplateRmqDest" default-delivery-mode="PERSISTENT" >

<!-- Channel 2  -->
<int:channel id="two" ></int:channel>
<int:channel id="error2" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="error2" logger-name="log2" />
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory2" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="XX.XX.XX.XX:5672"  cache-mode="CONNECTION" virtual-host="/"/>
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="two" id="inboundChannelAdapter2"  queue-names="myqueue2" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  error-channel="error2" auto-startup="true"  channel-transacted="true" />
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryRmqDest2" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ:5672" cache-mode="CONNECTION" connection-cache-size="50" virtual-host="/"/> 
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateRmqDest2" connection-factory="connectionFactoryRmqDest2"/>
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="two" id="outboundChannelAdapter2" routing-key="keyMyQueue2" exchange-name="direct.exchange" amqp-template="rabbitTemplateRmqDest2" default-delivery-mode="PERSISTENT" />
```

With this configuration, errors on channel go to specific log file defined for log1 or log2, if error occurs on the inbound channel.

If the target broker Z (outbound channel adapter on the channel 2) fails i would like to log the error in the log "log2" but also requeue the message on the source Broker to prevent loose of message.

How can i do that? Needs to write some beans? I need to log error (on the inbound or outbound channel) in specfic log file defined for the channel to supevise it.

Thanks for your help.

Regards

**Edited on 12/03/2018**

### Channel configuration

```
<bean id="log" class="com.logger.Logger"/>

<!-- Logger -->
<int:channel id="one" ></int:channel>
<int:channel id="error1" ></int:channel>
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="processChannel1"  />  
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="processChannel1" logger-name="log1" level="ERROR"/>   
<int:service-activator input-channel="processChannel1"  ref="log" output-channel="error1" />

<!-- Source -->
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="XX.XX.XX.XX:5672" cache-mode="CONNECTION" virtual-host="/" />
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="one" id="inboundChannelAdapter1" queue-names="myqueue" connection-factory="connectionFactory" error-channel="processChannel1" channel-transacted="true" advice-chain="retryInterceptor" />

<!-- Destination -->
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryRmqDest" username="guest" password="guest111" addresses="YY.YY.YY.YY:5672" cache-mode="CONNECTION" connection-cache-size="50" virtual-host="/" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateRmqDest" connection-factory="connectionFactoryRmqDest" />
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="one" id="outboundChannelAdapter1" routing-key="keyMyQueue" exchange-name="direct.exchange" amqp-template="rabbitTemplateRmqDest" default-delivery-mode="PERSISTENT"/>
```

### Logger.java

```
package com.logger;
public class Logger {

    public Message<?> log(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("*************************************");
        throw new AmqpException("Error on channel");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just log error:

```
error-channel="error2"
...
<int:channel id="error2" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="error2" logger-name="log2" />
```

The `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` treats it like a good finish of the message processing. To make it requeue the failed message, you should re-throw an exception from the error flow. For this purpose I would suggest to change that `error2` to the `<publish-subscribe-channel>` and add one more `<service-activator>` as subscriber. And that last one will throw an exception to the AMQP channel for requeing.

Comment: I edited my question with your remarks. Having an error on the auth, I have two stacktrace in log file:
 - first is the amqp exception because my credentials are worng:
  ....Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
 - second is due to the Logger :
  .... Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: Error on channel

How can i have only one in the log file. 
Is it possible to have only the cause message in the log file instead of the stack trace?

Comment: For this purpose the `<int:logging-channel-adapter>` suggests an `expression` option. So, you can have it like this `expression="payload.message"`, where `payload` is a `MessagingException` and that `message` is a call for the `Exception.getMessage()`

Comment: I only have the message of the exceptions. That's good. But i still have two exceptions for each error : (fist one indicates ACCESS_REFUSED => OK) and the other line is :2018-03-12 16:09:01.615 [(inner bean)#4f801872-1] ERROR log1 - Message conversion failed

Comment: Looks like that's different story. Maybe would be better to raise a new SO question?